# .htaccess: rewrite url with params wont work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(lib|assets|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?p=index [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(lib|assets|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^(profiles\/\w+)$ index.php?p=profiles
```

Its about the last rule, I want to rewrite this URL:

> /profiles/Steve

to

> index.php?p=profiles&user=Steve

Now when I got to mysite/profiles/ it will works but now I need to add &u=Steve so:

```
RewriteRule ^(profiles\/\w+)$ index.php?p=profiles&u=$1
```

And when I go to mysite/profiles/Steve

I will get a 404 error.

Why does this not works and how to fix it?

EDIT:

Now I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/(.+?)/?$ index.php?p=profiles&u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(thanks to Jon Lin) 
but now I have this as output: (print_r($_GET);):

```
Array ( [p] => profiles/Steve )
```

I want:

```
Array ( [p] => profiles [u] => Steve )
```

Fixed, the rule most be before the other rewriterule`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the grouping around "profiles", you only want the second part of the path:

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/(.+?)/?$ index.php?p=profiles&u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @user3144435 Not sure how you can get that result using the above rule, it works fine for me.